# Change background-image dynamically every second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use the following code to add dynamically HTML string to a div element.
I would like to change the image every second after added HTML to the DOM.
But my code doesn't work. Where is my mistake?

```
var images = ["http://pathToImg1.jpg", "http://pathToImg2.jpg"];

    var result =   '<div class="result">'+
                      '<a href="'+url+'" target="_blank" id="resultTitle" class="resultTitle">'+urlTitle+'</a>'+
                      '<p id="resultDescription" style="height: 15px;">'+
                      '<div class="resultImg" style="background-image: url('+images[0]+');"></div>'+
                      '<span class="resultDescription" style="margin:0px 15px 0px 0;">'+description+'</span></p>'+
                      '<p id="resultUrl" class="resultUrl">'+url+'</p>'+
                   '</div>';

    $("#"+targetId).append(result);

    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
          var el = $(result).find(".resultImg");
          $(el).css('background-image', 'url("' + images[i] + '")');
          i = i + 1;
          if (i == images.length) {
            i =  0;
          }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: can you add your html and css too.

Comment: you should update `i` variable before setting the background also try to change `$(result).find(".resultImg")` with `$("#"+targetId).find(".resultImg")`

Comment: Where you have defined `url`, `urlTitle` and `description` variables that you are using in your template?

Comment: Create a JSFiddle, it will help you get the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've got an error there:

```
var el = $(result).find(".resultImg");
```

selecting a string contained in a `result` variable will give you no effect, so you need to select element from it's parent which you used for attaching result to.

this line need to be changed like this:

```
var el = $("#"+targetId).find(".resultImg");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$(result).find(".resultImg");` will not return an element. because result is a class. You have to replace it with `$(".result").find(".resultImg");`

Below is a working snippet.

```js
var images = ["http://images.financialexpress.com/2015/12/Lead-image.jpg", "http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg","https://static.pexels.com/photos/50704/car-race-ferrari-racing-car-pirelli-50704.jpeg"];
 var targetId = "example";

    var result =   '<div class="result">'+
                      '<a href="#" target="_blank" id="resultTitle" class="resultTitle">urlTitle</a>'+
                      '<div class="resultImg" style="background-image: url('+images[0]+');"></div>'+
                      '<span class="resultDescription" style="margin:0px 15px 0px 0;">description</span></p>'+
                   '</div>';

    $("#"+targetId).append(result);

    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
      var el = $(".result").find(".resultImg");
          $(el).css('background-image', 'url("' + images[i] + '")');
          i = i + 1;
          if (i == images.length) {
            i =  0;
          }
    }, 1000);
```

```css
#example{
  width:250px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.resultImg{
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid green;
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `var el = $(result).find(".resultImg");`

`result` dont have context as document, it should be `var el = $("#"+targetId).find(".resultImg");`

I replace the image from your code as color and use `"#"+targetId` as `#test` just to show you its working

```js
var images = ["blue", "red"];

    var result =   '<div class="result">'+
                      '<a href="" target="_blank" id="resultTitle" class="resultTitle">Result</a>'+
                      '<p id="resultDescription" style="height: 15px;">'+
                      '<div class="resultImg" style="background-color: '+images[1]+';">resultImg</div>'+
                      '<span class="resultDescription" style="margin:0px 15px 0px 0;">description</span></p>'+
                      '<p id="resultUrl" class="resultUrl">url</p>'+
                   '</div>';

    $("#test").append(result);

    var i = 0;
    
    setInterval(function() {
          var el = $("#test").find(".resultImg");
          el.css('background-color', images[i]);
          i = i + 1;
          if (i == images.length) {
            i =  0;
          }
    }, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var images = [];
images[0] = "url of your first image";
images[1] = "url of your second image";
images[2] = "url of your third image";
images[3] = "url of your fourth image";
images[4] = "url of your fifth image";
images[5] = "url of your sixth image";

var i = 0;
setInterval(fadeDivs, 1000);

function fadeDivs() {
    i = i < images.length ? i : 0;
    console.log(i)
    $('.product img').fadeOut(100, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', images[i]).fadeIn(100);
    })
    i++;
}
```

You can change the fadeIn and fadeOut time manually. And set the time when the image should change. I set it to 1 second (1000 milliseconds) now.